# Firebase Schedule Push Notification

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

In my project, when each user enters the app (Swift-iOS), they are updating their timestamp field to 24 hours after current time. The data tree in Firestore as shown following below. Each user data as document, consisted inside “users” collection.

```
users-collection
   user1-document
     username: nameA
     timestamp: 1574102072
   user2-document
     username: nameB
     timestamp: 1574102234
```

Unless they enter the app again in 24 hours and when the time based on their registered timestamp, is up, i want to send a push notification (FCM).

I have planned to schedule cloud function, but in that moment, cloud function has to read too many documents periodically (for ex. every 5 min) and find the timestamps which are over, to send notification. This is really costly way. Is there any alternative way to handle this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "read too many documents"?  You are not charged for documents that aren't returned from a query.

Comment: Dear Doug, cloud function needs to check the timestamp data of each user periodically to get which is over or not. So, to read the timestamp data of each user, function needs to get document of each user in users collection then it will bring cost. CF:: let usersRef = db.collection('users');
let allUsers = usersRef.get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data().timestamp);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest making your query filter the documents by time rather than querying the entire collection and checking the time on the client, so you only get the documents you need.  Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).  For example:

```
usersRef = db.collection('users').where('timestamp', '>', current_time);
```

If you limit the result set to find only the documents you actually need, the query will be much faster and less expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, if it will be one time operation, no problem. However, if 1000 users (for ex among 10.000 users) has not entered the app in 24 hours, with following filter above, my cloud function will find 1000 user (1000 read) to send notification. When we consider the lifetime of the app, approx. in everyday, such amount of read will be necessary only inform our users. Is it ok? Instead of that way,  when user can enter the app, can he setup a schedule (like alarm) to get notification after 24 hours?

Comment: Sure, you could try it another way if you don't like this way.

Comment: Thanks again for your method. Can you advise some 3rd party push notification service provider which can be scheduled by the app?

Comment: Recommendations for offsite tools and products are off topic for Stack Overflow.  Please do some web search, or post to a discussion forum such as Reddit to start a conversation.